# Nginx access html resource with or without extension

Tags: html, nginx

I want to access HTML resources with or without extension. Currently, I defined two location blocks as defined below.

```
location = /home {
        default_type "text/html";
        alias /var/www/html/home.html;
}
location = /home.html {
        default_type "text/html";
        alias /var/www/html/home.html;
}
```

How the above configuration should be written in a single location block?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try_files` to test for various filename matches, for example:

```
root /var/www/html;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.